# Xamarin - Removing UITapGestureRecognizer after trigger it

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I believe this one is easy. Sorry, I'm new in Xamarin...
I'd like to remove the listener after it's triggered. 
So, when I do the Tap, i'd like to destroy the listener. Any suggestion ?

```
UITapGestureRecognizer tapGesture = new UITapGestureRecognizer(() =>
    {
           Console.Writeline("tap");
           link.RemoveGestureRecognizer(????);
    });
    link.AddGestureRecognizer(tapGesture);
```

I don't know how to reference itself on the parameter that I placed "????"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a reference to the `UITapGestureRecognizer`, so you could do something like this:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer tapGesture = new UITapGestureRecognizer((obj) =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("tap");
    link.RemoveGestureRecognizer(obj);
});
link.AddGestureRecognizer(tapGesture);
```